# add large files in zip codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, zip

I'm keep searching for solutions of large amount of size of csv file from GUI.I have tried to do this by zip library which is provided by codeigniter.But facing some issues

I never try Zip solutions before today so i don't have much idea about it so may be i am wrong.

I exactly need like for all large csv files once creating then it will be save into
 below path

```
/var/www/html/FolderName/assets/Reports_FIle/
```

then all csv file which i had created it must be add into zip file 
and download that zip file

whenever i am try to add **small csv file size (In Kb) in zip that time its working fine**. but when **file size (In Mb) its not working**. Even zip file have some file size but in zip package not able to see any csv file.

below is my current code for getting zip file after creating zip files

Code :

```
    $value="/var/www/html/FolderName/assets/Reports_FIle/Report_2014_07_31_00_51_44_0";
    $zip_name="Report_".date("Y-m-d_h_i_s").".zip";
    $this->zip->read_file($value.".csv");
    $this->zip->download($zip_name);
    exit;
```

Comment: What error is it showing? Anything in *error_log*?

Comment: nope there is nothing to show in error_log

Answer (score 0):

PHP restricts the upload file size in a number of locations.

Check the `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` settings in your PHP.ini file isn't too low (the default is 2mb) and restart Apache.